# Ways around the Vue 2 restriction on single-root templates

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to modify a Vue component that's based on an HTML template tag. The trouble is that the parent page places this component inside an `<li>` tag:

```
<li>
    <my-custom-vue-component></my-custom-vue-component>
</li>
```

And the current component only contains an  tag:

```
<template>
    <a class="my-button" @click="doTheThing()">Press Me</a>
</template>
```

What I need to do is add some conditional logic to this (which is straightforward with v-if) so that one of the renderings displays a modal. The problem is, I can't get the modal tags into the component because of the restriction on a single root element.

I can't wrap the whole thing inside a `<div>` or `<span>` because this is part of a list, and it destroys the formatting. I can't put the `<div>` tags for the modal inside an `<a></a>` because that's invalid HTML. And while I can use v-if to render two different links depending on the condition, I can't put the `<div>` tags for the modal outside the template, otherwise nothing renders. I've considered creating a new component just for this but it's still going to have the same fundamental problem - it'll need a link in it and a modal, and I can't see any way of getting them both inside the same `<template>`.

My understanding is that this restriction is removed with Vue 3 but we're still on Vue 2, and there's no way I can upgrade just to do this work.

Is there any tricksy way I can contain the tags I need to creat modal inside a template with a link given the restriction on a single root tag?

Comment: modals normally overlay everything else on the screen, so it would seem you could easily have the modal component exist in a parent, grandparent, or even root component of your app, and then just have your `doTheThing` function emit or set some global/store var that activates the modal.

Comment: Maybe take a look at vue-fragment package and see if it provides any help for your case

Comment: Maybe [render function](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function#v-if-and-v-for) can help you.

Comment: @yoduh The trouble with that is that the parent page is cshtml, not vue, and I need access to our vuelidate components to verify the form controls inside the modal.

Comment: @init-qy I already tried v-if and v-else but while it'll let me render two different links, I don't see how it helps me get tags to construct the modal inside the component, which is wrapped in a single-root template tag?

Comment: could be a use case for [multiple Vue instances](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/application.html#multiple-application-instances).  mount a second instance somewhere that is just your modal, somewhere that makes more sense and/or is easier to manage.  it is possible for multiple Vue instances to talk with each other so a click handler in one instance can activate a modal in a second instance.